# FuelPHP - handling plural for i18n

Tags: internationalization, fuelphp

I am looking for the best way to handle i18n within FuelPHP.
We are currently using gettext but I find it pretty gruesome...

I love the way Symfony2 handles it with xliff files but unfortunately that is not natively available in Fuel.
One of the option of course will be using the [Lang class](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/lang.html) of the Framework but is there a way to handle pluralized strings with it, because I can't really find anything for that?

Any insights?

Comment: i had the same problem.. to solve, in some places, i have created 2 terms/words

Comment: @AndréGadonski, one for singulars and one for plurals? Works for many languages, but a dozen of languages have very complicated plural rules.

Comment: So you are saying that this feature is not supported, at least yet by the default Fuel i18n Lang class. Then I was thinking of extending the Fuel framework with the Symfony2 mechanism for handling internationalisation. Might worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, Lang only provides a means of fetching translated strings, optionally with variable replacing, but it doesn't have gettext functionality.

Even in XLIFF it isn't that easy (and only present in the 2.0 spec).

We're working on Fuel v2 at the moment, we can see if we can find a decent solution for this. I've added an issue for it: https://github.com/fuelphp/foundation/issues/5