# Caching catalogues from Symfony2 Translation component

Tags: caching, symfony, internationalization, fuelphp, xliff

I have been trying to figure out another way of handling i18n within FuelPHP (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927771/fuelphp-handling-plural-for-i18n)).

I decided to import the [Symfony2 Translation component](https://github.com/symfony/Translation) (using composer) to Fuel as a vendor and manage i18n with xliff files.

Here is my (simplified) code:

```
use \Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use \Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector;
use \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader;

...

class I18N
{

    private static $translator = NULL;

    ....

    public static function get($key)
    {
        # Load and configure the translator
        self::$translator = new Translator('en_GB', new MessageSelector());
        self::$translator->addLoader('xliff', new XliffFileLoader());
        self::$translator->addResource('xliff', 'path/to/xliff/file', 'en');

        # Get the translation
        $translation = self::$translator->trans($key, $params);

        # Return the translation
        return $translation;
    }

}
```

So at first I thought that was working great since I was testing it on a very small xliff file but now that I've generated the complete xliff catalogue (about 1400 entries) for my entire application, each request is really slow.

So the question is, is there a way to cache translations when using the [Translation component](https://github.com/symfony/Translation) the same way the whole Symfony2 Framework caches it natively?

The [Translator Class from the FrameworkBundle](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/Translation/Translator.php) has a constructor that accepts options in which you can define the cache_dir. Anyway I can achieve that using the [Translation component](https://github.com/symfony/Translation)?

Thanks for any help on that matter.

Comment: Is there anything wrong using the Translator class from the FrameworkBundle? I mean, copying the `loadCatalogue` method to suit your needs?

Comment: The Translator class from the FrameworkBundle is meant to be used within the Symfony Framework. It's constructor expects a container interface. But yes I guess I'm going to try to generate my own php cache file so that the Translator component can use it when the file exists.

Comment: I mean, you should create your own Translator. You don't have to copy the constructor part, just adapt it to your needs. You can also use the `Config\ConfigCache` component

Comment: Exactly what I did and works like a charm now.

Answer (score 2):

So what I did was to generate my own cache from xliff files, if it doesn't exist, which is nothing more than the translations as a php array and make the Translator Component load resources as ArrayLoader instead of XliffFileLoader. It's lightning fast now. Thanks to Touki in the comments for your interest.